# How do i convert DBNull to 0 in .net c#?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I have a error which is a result of a `null` value. I want all `null` values to display as a `0`. How do I do this?

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

This is the line flagged up.

```
Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "December2013DailyOrderCount"));
```

Comment: Add a special case for DbNull?

Comment: What is the underlying type of `December2013DailyOrderCount`: if `number(something) null` then have you considered casing to `decimal?` and checking its `HasValue` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to modify your SQL to use `ISNULL` to convert null into a default value.

Otherwise you need conditional logic in your web application code. How easy this is depends on the context. In markup (eg. item template) it can be harder, in code behind just get the underling value into a temporary, and if null return 0.

Comment: I opted for this method as it's easier and for internal use only.

Answer (score 0):

Just do an additional check on the value being `DBNull.Value`:

```
var input = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "December2013DailyOrderCount");
var x = (input == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : (decimal)input;
```

Another option is to fix this in your query, like this:

```
select coalesce
       ( December2013DailyOrderCount
       , 0
       )
       December2013DailyOrderCount -- column alias!!!
from   xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var value = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "December2013DailyOrderCount");
Convert.ToDecimal(value == DbNull.Value ? 0 : value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its good to create a code behind function and call the function while binding the data:

```
protected decimal ConvertNullDecinalToZero(object val){
  decimal number;
  if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
     return number
 else
     return 0; 
}


var input = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, Convert("December2013DailyOrderCount"));
```

Comment: This is better than inline code for each case, but would be better with a better name (eg. "ConvertAndDefaultNullableDecimal"), "Convert" is an extremely generic name for a specific function.

Comment: @Richard edited. If you like the answer you can always upvote.